# DB design: how to deal with a table that has non-unique foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `products` and a `categories` table both of which optionally can have related records in the `images` table.

`images.fk` with a value of `1` could point to `categories.id` or `products.id`, therefore I have added a column `images.related_to`.

When I want to retrieve a category and its images I use

```
WHERE categories.id = images.fk AND images.related_to = 'categories'
```

But obviously now if the category doesn't have an image my query will return nothing because of the `WHERE images.related_to = 'categories'`.

I could resolve this by first running a query to see if the category has an image, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Is it considered bad design to have `images.fk` not contain unique values?
Should I have separate `categories.images` and `products.images` tables? Then what if I also have images for `users`, `shops`, `suppliers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about `images`, as it were a multi purpose image storage. Make `images` primary key `auto_increment` and don't store image fk in this table: `images(image_id, src, size, etc... , Primary(image_id))`.

Create one (or three) more table (simplified code): `images_on_categories (category_id, image_id, Primary(category_id, image_id))`.

Or: `images_on_users (user_id, image_id, Primary(user_id, image_id))`.

You can create FK like this: `FOREIGN KEY (images_on_users.user_id) REFERENCES users (users.user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Two more tables say

ProductImages(ProductId,ImageId) CategoryImages(CategoryID,ImageID)

Then ProductImages has a FK to Products and and FK To Images

and

CategoryImages has a FK to Categories and an FK To Images

is the classic solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood Ok your issue I will do it this way:

- The Cardinality between products and Categories is N:M (a product can have multiple categories and one category belongs to multiple Products
- I added another Table called "IMAGES", one product can have Multiple images and one image belong to one product, so the cardinality would be 1:N

You just have to add the others attributes.

[image]